# Using RadioButtons as variables Error

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tkinter

Here is a sample code I have constructed to use Tkinter to select a specific department, and find the products associated with it. Under my code is a dummy version of what the csv file looks like.

```
from tkinter import*
import pandas as pd 


root = Tk()

Department = StringVar()
Department.get()
Department.set("DepartmentA")

Radiobutton.config(textvariable=Department) 

Label(root, textvariable=Department).pack()

Radiobutton(root, text="DepartmentA", variable=Department, value="DepartmentA").pack()
Radiobutton(root, text="DepartmentB", variable=Department,value="DepartmentA").pack()
Radiobutton(root, text="DepartmentC", variable=Department, value="DepartmentA").pack()


fileread = pd.read_csv('50.csv', encoding='latin-1')
filevalue = fileread.loc[fileread['Customer'].str.contains(Department, na=False),"Product"]
root.mainloop()
```

Here is a dummy csv file:

[image]

I am, however getting the following error:

```
   Radiobutton.config(textvariable=Department) 
TypeError: configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I am unsure why I am getting this error and other questions with this error on StackOverFlow have failed to be helpful for solving this problem. Any ideas on how I can print the product values given the specific departments that I choose? I do not believe this is a duplicate question because I do not know how to link the variable to specifically the RadioButtons

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Comment: @DYZ Just editted it in!

Comment: What is `basefileread`? Please construct an example that can actually be executed.

Comment: @DYZ Tt is just fileread, I changed the code when entering into this question from basefileread to fileread so its more comprehensible.

Comment: `Department` is a StringVar, not a string. What you need is its value: `Department.get()`.

Comment: @DYZ I was unable to fix my code from that example, I am having trouble because of the RadioButtons.

Comment: But I already told you in a comment how to fix it.

Comment: @DYZ I have edited my question to show what I have done, that method and it is giving me that error.

Comment: That's not what I suggested.

Comment: @DYZ Okay can you please tell me what I did wrong then. I used the Department.get() you suggested

Comment: Your problem was on the line `filevalue = fileread.loc...` That's where you should fix it: `str.contains(Department.get(),...`

Comment: @DYZ Oh okay thank you